# Solutions to a diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

I tried to find integer solutions to the following diophantine equation $$x^3 - 3y^3 + 5z^3 - 3xy^2 + 3x^2y + 9xz^2 + 7x^2z + 3yz^2 - 3y^2z + xyz = 0$$ but was unable to do so. I suspect that there are no (nontrivial) solutions, but am unable to prove it. How would one prove this?

Comment: Is there any significance to this equation, or is it more the case of being just something suspected to have no solutions?

Comment: You might want to add the tag elliptic curves.  As my answer describes, the general theory of such cubic equations doesn't really belong to elementary number theory, but rather to the theory of elliptic curves.

Comment: Not any $x^2z$ term -- is that intended?

Comment: No it is not intended.

Comment: To the OP: I saw you accepted my answer.  I wonder --- were you able to carry out any of these steps.  (I am just curious whether your curve actually has local points, and so lies in Sha, or not.  Or maybe you found a global point after all?)

Comment: Here are two integral points: $(x,y,z)=(−2,−1,1),(−1,−1,1)$. The Weierstrass form of the elliptic curve (if we take it as homogeneous and then dehomogenise) is $y^2=x^3−562032/125x+1867860864/15625$ and it has rank 1 and $E(\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @sdf: Nice!  These are pretty small height!  I wonder how the OP missed them?

Comment: @MayankPandey I see you now have put in the $7x^2z$ term which was not there initially, and that "sdf" has found two nontrivial integer solutions $(-2,-1,1),(-1,-1,1)$ to this version. I still haven't found any to the older version (without the $7x^2z$ term...

Comment: Can you show me how you turned it into an elliptic curve?

Comment: @MayankPandey There are algorithms for doing this sort of thing. See e.g. [here](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~vlasenko/MA342J/wf.pdf). But it is easiest to use computer software, e.g. Magma has an implementation, try the code PP<x,y,z>:=ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(),2); C:=Curve(PP,x^3 - 3*y^3 + 5*z^3 - 3*x*y^2 + 3*y*x^2 + 9*x*z^2 + 7*z*x^2 + 3*y*z^2 - 3*z*y^2 + x*y*z); P0:=C![-1,-1,1]; E:=EllipticCurve(C,P0); WeierstrassModel(E);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about your equation in particular, but in general this can be 
delicate.  If you dehomogenize the equation (say by dividing through by the $z$ variable), you get a plane cubic, and you are looking for rational solutions.

The first thing to do is to test if this cubic is smooth; this is straightforward.
If it's not smooth, the whole thing becomes comparatively easy, since singular cubics are rational
curves.

If the cubic is smooth, then the question is harder.  To begin with,
you look over $\mathbb R$ and over $\mathbb Q_p$ for each prime $p$
and see if you have solutions there; this is again easy, at least in principal.
If there aren't solutions over one of these fields, then there are no rational
solutions, and you're done.

If there are solutions over $\mathbb R$ and each $p$-adic field, then you 
have a cubic curve which is so-called *locally trivial*, so it is an element
in the Shafarevic--Tate group of its Jacobian.

You can compute this Jacobian (see e.g. [this paper](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/villegas/publications/jacobian-cubics.pdf)); it will be another plane cubic, which has a
rational point at infinity.  Let's call it $E$ (for *elliptic curve*).   And your plane cubic (lets call it $C$) is an element of order dividing $3$ in the
Shafarevic--Tate group of $E$.    What you want to know is whether or not it's
the trivial element (i.e. whether or not it has a rational point).

Now since your curve is explicit and its coefficients are not too large,
I think that it's likely that $E$ will appear in standard tables of elliptic 
curves, and you can see whether its Shafarevic--Tate group contains non-trivial
$3$-torsion elements.  If it doesn't, then actually your curve $C$ has a
rational point.   If it it's Sha does contain non-trivial $3$-torsion elements, 
then you have to determine whether your curve $C$
actually corresponds to one of these non-trivial $3$-torsion points.

This should be checkable, but at this point I'm not quite sure how you're 
supposed to actually check this.  [Actually, I guess in principle what you
do is use the action of $E$ on $C$ to construct a certain $1$-cocyle for
an appropriate Galois group which describes (a preimage of) $C$ in
the Selmer group.  You also look at a table of elliptic curves to find
all the rational points on $E$, so that you know how much of the Selmer group
comes from Mordell--Weil.  And then you determine whether your cocycle is one
of those which does come from a rational point.  I think this should all be
effective in principle, but I've never carried it out, and I don't know how
horrendous it is in practice.  Presumably there are sensible short-cuts and
reinterpretations that yield a more efficient approach than the one I've
just described.]

---

Summary:  First check smoothness, then check over $\mathbb R$ and all $\mathbb Q_p$.
If $C$ is smooth and has points over all these local fields, the question can become quite delicate.